# How to extract route params from a complex url which has symbols like '?' , '&'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a URL which looks like this

**url:'/reset/password?email=:userEmail&reset_token=:passwordResetToken'**

but trying to access it simply using **$stateParams.passwordResetToken** returns **undefined**

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate more; In Angular colon part is not needed '=:'

```
url:'/reset/password?email=userEmail&reset_token=passwordResetToken'
```

In controller you can inject the **$stateParams** and then you won't get undefined

Comment: i'm using : so that the stateParams can fetch it. Yes i have injected $stateParams in my controller.

Comment: $stateParams.reset_token will have the value passwordResetToken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service, this service is created to parse urls in AngularJS.

This should work

```
$location.search() // will return {email: 'userEmail', reset_token: 'passwordResetToken'}
```

also you can use

```
$location.search('userEmail')
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your URL, I think you are using route like this :

```
.state('something.resetPassword', {
    url: "/reset/password",
    params: {
        email: null,
        reset_token: null 
    },
    templateUrl: 'your_template.html'
})
```

Then you should access parameters by using `$stateParams` as :

```
$stateParams.email        //gives email 
$stateParams.reset_token  //gives token
```

Hope this would help you!

Answer (score 0):

**url : '/reset/password?:email&:reset_token&:role'** Solved the problem